# ElasticSearch index exists not working / reliable

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am writing a simple Java wrapper around ElasticSearch's admin client. To test it I have a main method that first checks if an index exists (IndicesExistsRequest), if so deletes it (DeleteIndexRequest), and creates the index again. See code below. Yet I consistently get an IndexAlreadyExistsException.

By the way I am trying to get a client for the node that you start from the command prompt (by simply typing "elastic search"). I have tried every combination of methods on nodeBuilder's fluent interface, but I can't seem to get one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ElasticSearchJavaClient esjc = new ElasticSearchJavaClient("nda");
    if (esjc.indexExists()) {
        esjc.deleteIndex();
    }
    esjc.createIndex();
    URL url = SchemaCreator.class.getResource("/elasticsearch/specimen.type.json");
    String mappings = FileUtil.getContents(url);
    esjc.createType("specimen", mappings);
}

final Client esClient;
final IndicesAdminClient adminClient;
final String indexName;

public ElasticSearchJavaClient(String indexName) {
    this.indexName = indexName;
    esClient = nodeBuilder().clusterName("elasticsearch").client(true).node().client();
    adminClient = esClient.admin().indices();
}

public boolean deleteIndex() {
    logger.info("Deleting index " + indexName);
    DeleteIndexRequest request = new DeleteIndexRequest(indexName);
    try {
        DeleteIndexResponse response = adminClient.delete(request).actionGet();
        if (!response.isAcknowledged()) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to delete index " + indexName);
        }
        logger.info("Index deleted");
        return true;
    } catch (IndexMissingException e) {
        logger.info("No such index: " + indexName);
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean indexExists() {
    logger.info(String.format("Verifying existence of index \"%s\"", indexName));
    IndicesExistsRequest request = new IndicesExistsRequest(indexName);
    IndicesExistsResponse response = adminClient.exists(request).actionGet();
    if (response.isExists()) {
        logger.info("Index exists");
        return true;
    }
    logger.info("No such index");
    return false;
}

public void createIndex() {
    logger.info("Creating index " + indexName);
    CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
    IndicesAdminClient iac = esClient.admin().indices();
    CreateIndexResponse response = iac.create(request).actionGet();
    if (!response.isAcknowledged()) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create index " + indexName);
    }
    logger.info("Index created");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured out a solution. Since the java client's calls are done asynchronously you have to use the variant which takes an action listener. The solution still gets a bit contrived though:

```
// Inner class because it's just used to be thrown out of
// the action listener implementation to signal that the
// index exists
private class ExistsException extends RuntimeException {
}

public boolean exists() {
    logger.info(String.format("Verifying existence of index \"%s\"", indexName));
    IndicesExistsRequest request = new IndicesExistsRequest(indexName);
    try {
        adminClient.exists(request, new ActionListener<IndicesExistsResponse>() {
            public void onResponse(IndicesExistsResponse response) {
                if (response.isExists()) {
                    throw new ExistsException();
                }
            }
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                ExceptionUtil.smash(e);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ExistsException e) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can also execute a synchronous request like this:

```
boolean exists = client.admin().indices()
    .prepareExists(INDEX_NAME)
    .execute().actionGet().isExists();
```

Comment: Note that if `INDEX_NAME` is an alias for an existing index, this call will also return `true`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution when using RestHighLevelClient client;

Here a code-snippet: :

```
public boolean checkIfIndexExists(String indexName) throws IOException {
            Response response = client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest("HEAD", "/" + indexName);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
            return (statusCode != 404);
    }
```

A contribution for someone else !

Answer (score 5):

The [skgemini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012506/1344008) is ok if you want to check if index is available by the actual *index name* or any of its *aliases*.

If you however want to check only by the *index name*, here is how.

```
public boolean checkIfIndexExists(String index) {

    IndexMetaData indexMetaData = client.admin().cluster()
            .state(Requests.clusterStateRequest())
            .actionGet()
            .getState()
            .getMetaData()
            .index(index);

    return (indexMetaData != null);

}
```

Comment: worked for me, I think this should be the best answer since `client.admin().indices().prepareExists("indexName")  .execute().actionGet().isExists();` always returns `false`, although `indexName` exists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but i didn't like the solution which uses an ActionListener. ElasticSearch also offers a Future variant (at least at version 6.1.0).

Here a code-snippet:

```
public boolean doesIndexExists(String indexName, TransportClient client) {
    IndicesExistsRequest request = new IndicesExistsRequest(indexName);
    ActionFuture<IndicesExistsResponse> future = client.admin().indices().exists(request);
    try {
        IndicesExistsResponse response = future.get();
        boolean result = response.isExists();
        logger.info("Existence of index '" + indexName + "' result is " + result);
        return result;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        logger.error("Exception at waiting for IndicesExistsResponse", e);
        return false;//do some clever exception handling
    }
}
```

May be this helps someone else too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This works on Elasticsearch 7.x:

```
public boolean indexExists(String indexName) throws IOException {
    return client.indices().exists(new org.elasticsearch.client.indices.GetIndexRequest(indexName), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}
```