# IndicesExistsResponse.isExists() not working for embedded ElasticSearch instance

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the following java code to create instance of ElasticSearch instance and create a index called "testindex".

```
Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                                                      .put("path.data", "/etc/elasticsearch")
                                                      .put("cluster.name", "testcluster"))
                                      .node();
Client client = node.client();
IndicesAdminClient indices = client.admin().indices();
IndicesExistsResponse res = indices.prepareExists("testindex").execute().actionGet();
if(!res.isExists()){ //Everytime getting value as false
  CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder = indices.prepareCreate("testindex");
  createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet(); // Erring out with IndexAlreadyExistsException
}
```

Before creating the index I am checking whether index exists or not, I only create the index if it exists.
Second time when I am running the above code, it fails with IndexAlreadyExistsException.
It seems like the IndicesExistsResponse.isExists() is not behaving correctly.

Above code works fine if default elasticsearch.yml file is present in the classpath. IndicesExistResponse.isExists() returns true if elasticsearch.yml is in the classpath.

Any workaround to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883110/elasticsearch-index-exists-not-working-reliable

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at:

```
if(res.isExists()){
...
}
```

You want to create the index if it exists.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake while copying the code. I edited code in my question.