# Search phase execution exception with reason all shards failed

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am working on elastic search in spring boot REST API. I am getting the following exception while executing search query with ElasticSearch Java Client.

`org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]`

Following is my code:

```
        String query = path + "\"" + path + "\"";
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        request.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.fromOptions(true, true, true, true));
        String [] indices = new String[]{"index1", index2"};
        request.indices(indices);
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query);
        sourceBuilder.size(1);
        sourceBuilder.fetchSource("field_1", null);
        sourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
        request.source(sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = elasticsearchClient.getRestClient().search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT); ---> This line is throwing error.
```

And this issue seems intermittent during initialisation of ES and when indices are being created. Once after creation of indices, this issue is not occurring.

Can anyone help me on how we can eat this issue smoothly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you said this is related to ES missing indices (not initialized yet). Maybe check if the indeces exist before trying to execute the search. `boolean exists = client.admin().indices().prepareExists(INDEX_NAME).execute().actionGet().isExists();` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883110/elasticsearch-index-exists-not-working-reliable

Comment: It might be useful for other people: I had same error message when I had Index and tried to search for data, but I had no mapping. Creating Index again together with mapping solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to query the index which is being created
if that is the case try to query **without specifying the index**
which will avoid error **or wait until the index creation** is over which may resolve your issue